# PhpStorm React components strange color

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

Today I restarted my PC and when I launched my React project in PhpStorm I found that all React components usages are in green color. They used to be in yellow as these in the middle. Has anyone seen something like this?

[image: See]

Comment: Looks like, it is a default color for custom tag now. Since 2022.3.1, it is possible use set different color for tags:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52334/Color-scheme-make-it-possible-to-set-different-Component-and-Tag-colors#focus=Comments-27-5596272.0-0

Answer (score 3):

JSX tags are colored according to **Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | XML, Custom Tag Name** settings; you can specify the desired foreground color there